# Windows 10 Alt+Tab and Opening Programs Use Display That Mouses is on

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, mouse, alt-tab

I used to use Ubuntu for my web devlopment, but I've had to switch to Windows because of Windows being able to handle dual Nvidia cards much more nicely. Anyways, in Ubuntu, if I pressed Alt+Tab, the menu would show up on the screen that the mouse was currently on, and if I opened a program (like terminal with Alt+Ctrl+T), it would show up on the same display.

However in Windows, the Alt+Tab menu always shows up on the main screen, and explorer.exe does some weird thing where it opens on the last screen that another explorer.exe windows was open, which is even more confusing.

Is there anyway to mimic the Ubuntu functionality in this case on Windows 10?